# Where did the word 'dismantle' come from?

Tags: etymology

I know that *mantle* has many different meanings...

Noun:

- a garment (loose, sleeveless cloak/cape)
- something that covers, envelops, or conceals
- the part of the Earth between the crust and the core
- part of a shell in mollusks/brachiopods
- a wooden/stone frame around the opening of a fireplace

Verb:

- to spread or cover a surface
- to blush
- to spread the wings and tail (of a hawk or falcon) over food

So how did the word *dismantle* *(to disassemble/pull down; to deprive of defenses)* come about?  One would think that they are opposites!

Comment: I'm not sure why it isn't an opposite -- mantle is clothing, dismantle is taking the "covering" off something

Answer (score 4):

Per [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=dismantle&searchmode=none), it comes from [Middle French](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_French) (roughly the period from 1340 to 1611):

> 1570s, from M.Fr. *desmanteler*: "to tear down the walls of a fortress,"
>   lit. "strip of a cloak," from des- "off, away" (see dis-) + manteler
>   "to cloak" (see mantle).
>
> Related: Dismantled; dismantling.